# Using Facebook SDK and retrieving unique application facebook ID's

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to make an app in which a user imports their friends from Facebook into my app. The user of my app would then select 2 of their friends, a match request is sent to the people in facebook, and if they both accept they download my app and a match is made in my app. However, according to my research, this isn't possible because they both would have needed to download the app before a match is made. This is due to restrictions on unique facebook IDs to my app, which every app gets uniquely. Is there any way around this?

Comment: In API v2.0 and later you will only be able to get friends that are using the app and not all friends. How to invite people to your app is answered at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find matches in this way:

1. Store two user IDs in your server after sending match requests
2. Check the match maker's friends list periodically
3. If two stored ids are in the list, they are matched.

You might need to check they are already using your app before sending a request.

How-to:

1. Use Request dialog to import friends (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.2#invoking_ios).
2. You will receive the request id after the success and can query user IDs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/request)
3. Store user IDs, and check them periodically.

Comment: I want to allow a "matchmaker" to import their friends from facebook into the app, and choose 2 that would be sent a match request ala a Candy Crush request in facebook. However, the user who is being sent the match request may not already have the app. The one being matched may receive a message such as, "Karen has sent you a match request! Download (name of app) to see who you've been matched with."

Comment: Then, the person who was sent the match would download the app, see who've they've been matches with (who may not have the app either) and if they like what they see, accept the match. Then, the other match party would have to accept as well. After this, the match is made within the app. Is this possible?